# Sticky navbar disappearing after passing main section

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I can't seem to get my sticky navbar to be sticky all the way through to the bottom of the page, it disappears after i pass the .main div.

I've tried different z-indexes

https://jsfiddle.net/pcLohe1v/1/ <-- better example

```css
/* navbar */

nav {
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1 !important;
  font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px #999;
  transition: top .4s;
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul.navbar-nav li {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

nav li a {
  / color: #000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  */
  /* wave effect */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, var(--mainColor) 0%, var(--mainColor) 100%);
  background-position: 0 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 3px 3px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  */
}

nav li a:hover {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg id='squiggle-link' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xmlns:ev='http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events' viewBox='0 0 20 4'%3E%3Cstyle type='text/css'%3E.squiggle{animation:shift .3s linear infinite;}@keyframes shift {from {transform:translateX(0);}to {transform:translateX(-20px);}}%3C/style%3E%3Cpath fill='none' stroke='%23404d91' stroke-width='2' class='squiggle' d='M0,3.5 c 5,0,5,-3,10,-3 s 5,3,10,3 c 5,0,5,-3,10,-3 s 5,3,10,3'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-position: 0 100%;
  background-size: auto 6px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #404d91;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

nav button {
  border: 2px solid #000 !important;
}

nav button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

nav img {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100px;
}


/* collapse button svg change coor */

.custom-toggler.navbar-toggler {
  border-color: rgb(255, 102, 203);
}

.custom-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(0,0,0, 1)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}


/* main */

.main {
  background: url(../img/good1-min.JPG) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  display: table;
  height: calc(100% - 104px);
  height: -o-calc(100% - 104px);
  /* opera */
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 104px);
  /* google, safari */
  height: -moz-calc(100% - 104px);
  /* firefox */
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.main .container img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

/* showcase1 & showcase2 */
.showcase1,
.showcase2 {
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.showcase1 p,
.showcase2 p {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #32383e;
}

.showcase1 h1,
.showcase2 h1 {
  font-size: 64px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md sticky-top" id="scroll" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Logo -->
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="img/logo.svg" alt="logo">
    </a>
    <!-- Collapse Button -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler custom-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- Navbar dropdown -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="nav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <!-- Navbar links -->
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link linkB" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link linkB" href="#Kontakt">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link linkB" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- main -->
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="img/_logo_a4.svg" alt="logo">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- showcase1 -->
<div class="showcase1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 animated fadeInLeft">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/s1.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1>Lorem.</h1>
        <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
        <p class="bold">lorem ipsum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I expect the navbar to be sticky all the time but its  hiding after for some reason. I don't know what to do or why this is happening.

Comment: create a fiddle and upload u r code and share the link @sn1b

Comment: just add position:fixed; to nav.

Comment: I don't see anything sticking anywhere

Comment: Define "sticky" in your world it is "stays at the top of the page" or "floats at the top of the window" or something else.   Add bootstrap to your snippet perhaps

Comment: @AmareshSM  I believe this should be reproducible in the snippet and not need an external page

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pcLohe1v/1/ Made a fiddle that shows this in action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is :

```
html, body {
    /* set the body's height to the height of the viewport */
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Try `min-height: 100%;` instead.**
For example, if you set your body/html with `overflow: hidden;` there won't be any scroll bar. That's because everything you currently see in your fiddle beyond the height of your viewport is overflown content.
At 100% of the viewport your `sticky` nav has reached the end of it's container and scroll with it (as it is supposed to) !

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Pi_L/2w1ue0yv/) is a fork of your fiddle with this CSS modified :

```
html, body {
    /* height: 100%; */
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how i can make the main page height cover the screen with min-height: 100% on html & body instead of height: 100%?

Comment: If you are talking about the `.main` class then, as your navbar seems to be 42px high : `.main { height: calc(100vh - 42px);` } will do the trick. `1vh` mean 1% of the viewport height. That being said, depending how your `.main` childrens are set up you might get some overflow depending on the screen height.

Answer (score 0):

Works Perfectly. The issue could be with the placement of the bootstrap and jquery scripts.

```css
nav {
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1 !important;
  font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px #999;
  transition: top .4s;
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul.navbar-nav li {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

nav li a {
  color: #000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  /* wave effect */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, var(--mainColor) 0%, var(--mainColor) 100%);
  background-position: 0 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 3px 3px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
 
}

nav li a:hover {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg id='squiggle-link' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xmlns:ev='http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events' viewBox='0 0 20 4'%3E%3Cstyle type='text/css'%3E.squiggle{animation:shift .3s linear infinite;}@keyframes shift {from {transform:translateX(0);}to {transform:translateX(-20px);}}%3C/style%3E%3Cpath fill='none' stroke='%23404d91' stroke-width='2' class='squiggle' d='M0,3.5 c 5,0,5,-3,10,-3 s 5,3,10,3 c 5,0,5,-3,10,-3 s 5,3,10,3'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-position: 0 100%;
  background-size: auto 6px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #404d91;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

nav button {
  border: 2px solid #000 !important;
}

nav button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

nav img {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100px;
}


/* collapse button svg change coor */

.custom-toggler.navbar-toggler {
  border-color: rgb(255, 102, 203);
}

.custom-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(0,0,0, 1)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}


/* main */

.main {
  background: url(../img/good1-min.JPG) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  display: table;
  height: calc(100% - 104px);
  height: -o-calc(100% - 104px);
  /* opera */
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 104px);
  /* google, safari */
  height: -moz-calc(100% - 104px);
  /* firefox */
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.main .container img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

/* showcase1 & showcase2 */
.showcase1,
.showcase2 {
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.showcase1 p,
.showcase2 p {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #32383e;
}

.showcase1 h1,
.showcase2 h1 {
  font-size: 64px;
}
```

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">  
 
      <head>
        <body>
          <!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md sticky-top" id="scroll" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Logo -->
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="img/logo.svg" alt="logo">
    </a>
    <!-- Collapse Button -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler custom-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- Navbar dropdown -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="nav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <!-- Navbar links -->
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link linkB" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link linkB" href="#Kontakt">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link linkB" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- main -->
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="img/_logo_a4.svg" alt="logo">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- showcase1 -->
<div class="showcase1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 animated fadeInLeft">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/s1.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1>Lorem.</h1>
        <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
        <p class="bold">lorem ipsum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
     
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  


  </body>

</html>
```